# C++ add pointers to structure

Tags: c++

I have problem with list with two-way pointers, I have structure that I need to use:

```
struct Uczestnik{
    enum Plec{K,M,W};

    Uczestnik(Plec p) : plec(p) {}
    Plec plec;
};
```

And i need to make class List that works like list with two way pointers, and elements are Uczestnik.

I don't know how to do this because `struct Uczestnik` doesn't have pointers like `Uczestnik* prev,next;`

Is there a way to make it happen without editing `struct Uczestnik`?

Comment: Always program in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply, create a class that has `Uczestnik` as a member variable.

```
struct UczestnikList {
    UczestnikList *next;
    UczestnikList *prev;
    Uczestnik val; // or Uczestnik* val;
};
```

Now you can use the `UczestnikList` and traverse through it.

Also note that `val` could be an embedded member variable or a pointer (`Uczestnik* val`) depending on how you wish to implement the list.

When you get more familiar with C++, you could use STL libraries for this, such as the doubly-linked list in [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/).

Comment: Why the -1 ? I am interested in understanding my errors and improve quality of SO.

Answer (score -1):

The modern way is like this

```
  template<Data> struct node
  {
      struct node *next;
      struct node *previous;
      Data data;
  }
```

Now instantiate it with your struct UczzestnikList.

Comment: 1) It should instantiate with Uczzestnik, not with UczzestnikList 2) `struct node * next` is redundant in C++, just `node * next`